# Setting AlertDialog to Linear View

Tags: android

I've been trying to set this alertDialog to a linearview by making it link to a xml file. But its not working. Any help would be appreciated, thanx

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
   .setCancelable(false)
   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MyActivity.this.finish();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do i get you right: You want to place a LinearLayout inside a AlertDialog?

```
LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) inf.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

builder.setView(myLayout);
```

Just replace `dialog_layout` with your Layouts XML.
Also you don't need the `builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")` anymore.

Comment: how would i refrence the button name in xml its not like ive just set a variable called button = yes; Do you have any idea regardless thanx

Comment: In XML say `<Button android:id="@+id/button1".... />` and in your Code you say `Button mButton = (Button)myLayout.findViewByID(R.id.button1));` But you can use the Positive and Negative Button like in your code above, too. They will be placed below the LinearLayout automatically.